# recursive nodes

Tags: python, recursion, nodes

I'm trying to understand within my lesson how to read the below function called printBackward. How is it that when I type `printBackward(node1)` and my output is 3,2,1 which is what it's suppose to do. I just don't understand why that is. See below how I interpret it and please school me on where I saw it wrong...

```
 class Node:
    def __init__(self, cargo = None, next = None): # optional parameters. cargo and the link(next) are set to None.
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cargo)


node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
node3 = Node(3)
node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3

# Exercise
def printList(node):

    print "[",
    while node:
        print node,
        node = node.next
        if node != None:
            print ",",
    print "]",
    print


def printBackward(list):
    if list == None: return
    head = list      
    tail = list.next 
    printBackward(tail) 
    print head,
```

So let's say... `printBackward(node1)` at first, `if list` should be ignored since node1 contains a reference to node2 so we move to `head = list` which is node1. `tail = list.next` which I see as node1.next = node2 so tail = node2. Then we get to `printBackward(tail)`which is node2. At that point, what happens? Do we do this all over again? I see this going up to node3 which at that point will return None. When do we get to `print head,`??? We make a recursive call before even getting to the `print head,`? Please educate me as I'm trying to understand the examples that are given to me within my lesson. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about everything that is happening leading up to when `printBackward(node3)` is called. What is going on is every time you get to the recursive `printBackward()` call, you go deeper into the call stack. The final `print` doesn't actually get called until the recursion stops calling `printBackward()`, and then unwinds. As it returns each time, THEN the `print` is called, which is why you get the backwards order. The `print`s happen during the unwinding of the call stack.
When you get to `node3`, `tail` becomes `None`, and that next call to `printBackwards()` is what returns right away, and the printing begins.

```
printBackward(node1)
    printBackward(node2)
        printBackward(node3)
            printBackward(None)
        print node3
    print node2
print node1
```

Also a small note, you are shadowing a few built-in python names (`list` and `next`).

Comment: so when we call printBackward(node3), if list THEN equals None, right? So wouldn't it return nothing? I'm probably looking past the obvious here but I don't see how this code is setup to begin printing backwards since we've reached a node3 that contains None which looks to me the end of the program?

Comment: notice that you arent actually interested in the return value is those code. you just call printBackward(). When it returns, its only returning from that specific call. If it makes it to the end, it is also returning None. Either way, that call returns None every time, its just a matter of WHEN it leaves the function

Comment: the problem I'm having is seeing that it's storing node1 and node2 as we hit node3 and print it. So it builds up without printing until we reached a list that has nothing further so it prints what was built up to that point? How does it know to start with 3,2,1 instead of 1,2,3?

Comment: btw someone edited out my little diagram and I put it back in.

Comment: Those variables are local to the space of each function call. So head and tail were what they were assigned during that call. Once the functions return and go back up the stack, those values are just printed. It really isnt building up any list.

Comment: It would read even more clearly if the function were called:  `def printBackward(thisNode)` or something like that. Since you could see that you aren't necc dealing with a list but really a Node instance each time. Though what you are replicating here is a linked list from lower level languages like C/C++

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I understand what you are saying. It's just not clicking with me in the way it prints backwards. I'm still a newb :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4181/discussion-between-g-g-and-jdi)

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is calling function itself. So let's see printBackward function's calling order.

```
printBackward(node1)
 |
 +-> printBackward(node2)
      |
      +-> printBackward(node3)
           |
           +-> printBackward(None)
          print node3
     print node2
print node1
```

As you can see, printBackward1 is called with node1 as argument. Before it prints node1, it gives the control flow to printBackward(node2). And when printBackward(node2) is finished, it prints node1.